How is energy in an electrochemical cell (e.g Daniell cell) conserved?
I wonder how energy is conserved in an electrochemical cell? A search did not provide a satisfactory answer.
In an electrochemical cell you put in some chemicals and their chemical energy is converted into electric energy. But what is actually chemical energy? How is it represented mathematically? And how can we show mathematically that energy is conserved?

I think it is a legit chemical question.

I do not understand what you mean when you ask how energy is conserved. It is simple, the electrochemical cell is based on an electrochemical reaction. If there is no reaction, there is no exchange of energy. Have you heard of enthalpy and Gibbs free energy of a reaction?

To obtain the mathematical expression you are looking you must chemical potentials. You should check a textbook on Chemical Thermodynamics or Physical Chemistry where this topic is usually discussed in more detail. You will need some knowledge of the formalism of Chemical Thermodynamics however.

Maybe this is useful as an appetiser https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-24847-9_3

Changes of chemical energy is on low level achieved by changes of energy of electrodynamic systems involving positively charged atomic nuclei and negatively charged electrons.  For more, you should study textbooks or equivalent material about classical and quantum physics and quantum chemistry. // Look e.g. at site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org OR site:wikipedia.org OR site:hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu chemical energy

Chemical energy comes back to essentially electrostatic interactions of electrons and nuclei, kinetic energy and Pauli repulsion. Suppose you are doing an electrochemical oxidation, then you remove an electron. This will usually be removed from the highest occupied state or Fermi level. This has a high energy because it is in a highly excited single-electron quantum state, the high energy resulting from its particular orbital properties that are connected to certain electrostatic, kinetic and Pauli interactions. Now in a redox reaction, you are transferring this electron to another compound which has an acceptor level lower than the energy level of the donator. Again, this is due to particular orbital properties of that acceptor level. After the redox reaction, the electron has transferred and has thus modified the total energies of the acceptor and donator. Now if you want to do work, the resistance of the cell should be infinite, there should be no redox current flowing, and the driving force for the electrons to transfer between donor and acceptor should just be used to do electrical work. Again electrical energy is related to electrostatics, you just utilize that high energy/chemical potential of the electron that is moving to do some electrical work, such as heating a light bulb. This is not a mathematical explanation, but a qualitative understanding of what is going on. Chemical energy is nothing special and also relates to the standard quantum mechanical forces such as every energy source.
